# Como mandar a llamar un Procedimiento Almacenado desde php con el patron MVC

Tags: php, mysql, angularjs

Buen dia, alguien sabe como puedo mandar llamar un procedimiento almacenado de Mysql desde PHP con el patron MVC, El procedimiento es para validar si un campo ya existe si existe manda un mensaje que no esta disponible y si no existe manda que el campo esta disponible

AQUI LES COMPARTO EL CONTROLADOR DEL FORMULARIO

> Cita en bloque

```
var App = angular.module('app', []);

App.controller('alumnoCtrl', function($scope, $http) {

    $scope.alumno = {};


    $scope.guardar = function() {

        $http.post('./modelo/guardarAlumno.php', $scope.alumno).success(function(data, status, headers, config) {

            alert(data);
            location.href = "./pdf/Ficha.php";
        }).error(function(data, status, headers, config) {
            alert("Error BD");

        })

    }


});
```

AQUI LES COMPARTO MI MODELO

```
<?php
error_reporting(E_ALL);
require_once 'conexion.php';
$obj = json_decode(file_get_contents("php://input"));
$stmt = $db->prepare("INSERT INTO gestion(Pk_gestion,N_control,Nombre_Completo,R1,R2,R3,R4,R5,R6,R7,R8,R9,R9_1,R10,R10_1,R11,R11_1,R12) VALUES 
(null,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)");

@session_start();

$stmt->bind_param('sssssssssssssssss',$obj->N_control,$obj->Nombre_Completo,$obj->R1,$obj->R2,$obj->R3,$obj->R4,$obj->R5,$obj->R6,$obj->R7,$obj->R8,$obj->R9,$obj->R9_1,$obj->R10,
$obj->R10_1,$obj->R11,$obj->R11_1,$obj->R12);
$stmt->execute();
$stmt->close();
$_SESSION['folio'] =$obj->N_control;

echo "Registro Almacenado\nPasará a la siguiente seccion";
?>
```

AQUI LES COMPARTO EL PROCEDIMIENTO ALMACENADO

```
BEGIN
    DECLARE CONTADOR INT;
    SELECT COUNT(*) INTO CONTADOR FROM gestion WHERE N_control=N_control;
    
    IF CONTADOR = 0 THEN
        SELECT 
            'N° Control DISPONIBLE' AS RESPUESTA, 
            '1' AS VALOR;
    ELSE
        SELECT 
            'ESTE N° Control YA ESTÁ SIENDO OCUPADO' AS RESPUESTA, 
            '2' AS VALOR;
    END IF;
```

Comment: ¿Por qué deseas hacer la validación en el servidor de base de datos y no haces una consulta en PHP para validar la información?

Comment: Quiero hacer la validacion del campo, si  es que existe me mande un alert que no esta disponible, antes de mandar a llamar el insert

Comment: Saludos Uriel, está bien pero lo que te quiero decir es que esa validación la debes hacer en PHP no directamente en el servidor de Base de Datos. Antes del INSERT haces en PHP un SELECT para validar si los datos ya se encuentran registrados, si no están registrados los registras.